# How to output clang input line from Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to build a project I inherited. In order to better understand how the project is organized , I'd like to see what flags Xcode sent to Clang. For example, if the build settings were:

```
clang -L"some/path" -I"/Some/Other/Path" file1.m file2.cpp
```

I'd like to see that line somehow. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is printed in the build log, the rightmost icon on the left panel looking like a comic balloon. Google images for "build log xcode" if you can't find it.

To show the full command line for a command select a line corresponding to a command then click on the icon appearing on the right part of the selected line (a rounded rect with horizontal lines on it)